Access IP WiFi Camera through my own website
I want to have a Wifi Camera, then access the video through a webpage I design myself. I want it to work out of the box without having to do port forwarding. Basically, connect the camera to the user's WiFi and the user can access video through my website. I'm a seasoned Software Engineer I just don't have much experience with this kind of stuff. Thanks!
I've looked into P2P cameras but they seem to only connect to the seller's website/app. Basic IP cameras need port forwarding changes that I don't want the user to deal with.
